Why is my App not changing it's content from English to other language[Lithuanian] on selecting the option specified in android?
I have an option in setting about changing the language of content to Lithuanian and English. Both the items are in the Spinner, so When i select the option of Lithuanian, the content of settings screen doesn't translate to Lithuanian but stays English itself. I have created separate strings.xml files too in separate values and values-lt folder. This is how my SettingsFragment lookMy settings screenBelow is my code of SettingsFragment.kt
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R
import com.example.visuallithuanian.adapter.SpinnerAdapter
import com.example.visuallithuanian.databinding.FragmentSettingsBinding
import com.example.visuallithuanian.ui.activities.FirstScreen
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import java.util.Locale


class SettingsFragment : Fragment() , AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private lateinit var binding:FragmentSettingsBinding
lateinit var bottomNav: BottomNavigationView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)


    // Taking the BottomNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
    bottomNav = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
    bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val languages = listOf(
        SpinnerAdapter.Language("English", R.drawable.englishuk),
        SpinnerAdapter.Language("Lithuanian", R.drawable.lithuania)
    )

    val adapter = context?.let { SpinnerAdapter(it, languages) }
    binding.spinnerLanguage.adapter = adapter





    return binding.root
}

override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    val selectedLanguage = (parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as SpinnerAdapter.Language).name
    when (selectedLanguage) {
        "English" -> setLocale("en")
        "Lithuanian" -> setLocale("lt")
    }
}

private fun setLocale(languageCode: String) {

    val locale = Locale(languageCode)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.setLocale(locale)
    context?.resources?.updateConfiguration(config, context?.resources?.displayMetrics)
    // Recreate the activity to apply the new locale
    activity?.recreate()

}

override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
}

Below is the code of my Adapter class
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R

class SpinnerAdapter(private val context: Context, private val languages: List<Language>):BaseAdapter() {

data class Language(val name: String, val flagResId: Int)
override fun getCount(): Int = languages.size

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any = languages[position]

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view: View = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false)
    val flag = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewFlag)
    val language = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewLanguage)

    val currentLanguage = languages[position]
    flag.setImageResource(currentLanguage.flagResId)
    language.text = currentLanguage.name

    return view
}
}

below is the layout file of my SettingsFragment.kt
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:background="@color/lime_green">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewAvatar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageAvatar"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAvatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:text="@string/select_your_avatar"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_card" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

following is the content in my strings.xml file created in the folder named values-lt
    <string name="select_your_avatar">Pasirinkite Savo Avatarą</string>
    

following content is in my strings.xml file created in the folder named values
SELECT YOUR AVATAR
I have created a Locale for changing the language from english to lithuanian as per the need but the content of settings screen doesn't change on clicking the lithuanian option from the spinner
